# Undefined index: when using php session

Tags: php

I am following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mn0ucCuNOTI.

The part that is wrong is that I have created a form where you have logged in with the following code and that code seems to work:

```
<?php include_once("db.php"); 
session_start();
?>
<?php
    $user = $_POST['name'];
    $pass = $_POST['pwd'];

     $sql="SELECT count(*) from phplogin WHERE(username='$user' and password='$pass')";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if($result[0]>0){
    $_SESSION['username']=$user;
    echo "Successful login!";

    echo "<br /> Welcome " .$_SESSION['username']. "!";
    echo "<br /><a href='signupform.php' > SignUp </a>";
    echo "<br /><a href='signinform.php' > SignIn </a>";
    echo "<br /><a href='logout.php' > LogOut </a>";
    }
    else{
    echo "Login failed!";
    echo "<br /><a href='signupform.php' > SignUp </a>";
    echo "<br /><a href='signinform.php' > SignIn </a>";
    }
?>
```

On that page there is a link that allows you to log out (in case you have signed in) and by clicking that link you reach the following code:

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
?>
<?php
    session_start(); #starts the session        

    session_unset(); #removes all variables in the session

    session_destroy(); # destroys the session

    if(!$_SESSION['username'])
        echo "Succesfully logged out";  

    else
        echo "Error occurred";  

    ?>
```

Then I get the following output when I run it on my localhost: Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\webserver\apache\htdocs\sign_in_up\logout.php on line 12

Successfully logged out

Comment: What happens in `db.php`, and is the file you showed `logout.php`?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Gumbo You aren't kidding, sheesh.

Comment: Okay, well now it's obvious. You destroyed and unset the session. You can't access `$_SESSION['username']` anymore because it doesn't exist. You could do `if (!array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION))` instead

Comment: @FilipEriksson You should place `session_start()` before that include, then as if the mysql functions fail for some reason, they will send output to the browser causing `session_start()` to fail.

Comment: Also, the closing `?>` php tag and subsequence opening `<?php` tag after the include are unnecessary if there is no non-php code in between. (HINT: there shouldn't be!)

Comment: Yes you are right crush 1. The weird thing is that I was following a tutorial in which it worked to write like that. What you are saying makes sence and it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['username'] doesn't exists. check if that variable name is correct i.e not UserName userName etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here with your scripts. I'll start by answering your question specifically. In `logout.php` you have the following code block:

```
session_start(); #starts the session        
session_unset(); #removes all variables in the session
session_destroy(); # destroys the session

if(!$_SESSION['username']) {
```

Here you start the session, then you unset all the variables in that session, then destroy the session.

1. You don't need to unset all the variables in the session before calling `session_destroy()`. It will unset all the variables for you automatically.
2. After you've unset or destroyed the session, no keys will exist in the super global array, `$_SESSION`. Thus, the key `'username'` does not exist in `$_SESSION` anymore where you are using it. Instead, you can check for the existence of that key:

PHP:

```
if (!array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)) {
    //Successfully logged out.
} else {
    //Error occurred.
}
```

---

### Other Issues

**MySql Injection**

As your code currently stands, it is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. What this means is that someone could pass in a value that would inject malicious, or unintended consequences into your MySql query.

```
$user = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql="SELECT count(*) from phplogin WHERE(username='$user' and password='$pass')";
```

Here, you take the values as they receive to the server, and plug them directly into your query string. But, what if someone sent `$_POST['name'] = "' OR 1=1 --"`? That would make your query look like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM phplogin WHERE (username = '' OR 1=1) --' and password='$pass')
```

If you didn't know, `--` is an SQL comment, meaning everything after that is ignored. Effectively, the above query is:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM phplogin WHERE (username = '' OR 1=1)
```

In this case, they'd get back a count of all records in the `phplogin` table, but it could've be worse on a more sensitive operation. For example, what if your query was meant to login an administrator. An unauthorized user could gain access to the administrative panel with this same method.

Instead, you should use prepared statements with either the [**PDO**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**mysqli_**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) libraries.

Comment: Your exploit won’t work as it’s missing the closing `)` to build a syntactically valid statement.

Comment: Furthermore, PHP’s MySQL extension doesn’t support multiple statements, so your `DROP TABLE` example won’t work either.

Comment: @Gumbo I stand corrected again. `mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.`

Answer (score 0):

instead of

if(!$_SESSION['username'])

try

if(empty($_SESSION['username']))